# How dynamic arrays store different datatypes?

Tags: python, list

How does the language know how much space to reserve for each element? Or does it reserve the maximum space possible required for a datatype? (Talk about large floating point numbers). In that case isn't it a bit inefficient?

Comment: PS: all floating point numbers are the same size: 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Python reserves only enough space in a list for a **reference** to the various objects; it is up to the objects' allocators to reserve enough space for them when they are *instantiated*.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Python are done via the `array` module. They do not store different datatypes, they store arrays of specific numerical values.

I think you mean the `list` type. It doesn't contain values, it just contains references to objects, which can be any type of object at all.

None of these reserves any space for any elements at all (well, they do, but that's internal implementation details). It adds the space for the elements needed when it they are added to the list/array.

The list type is indeed less efficient than the array type, which is why the array type exists.

Answer (score 0):

It is an array of references, just stores references to elements objects. So the size of each block is specific.

http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented

Answer (score 0):

In C language terms, a Python list is like a `PyObject *mylist[100]`, except it's dynamically allocated.  It's a contiguous chunk of memory storing references to Python objects.